# C++ Allocate Storage for Object without Initializing it?

Tags: c++

Is there an accepted idiom for allocating the backing store for an object in-place but not initializing it?  Here's my naive solution:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T> 
union Slot {
    T inst;

    Slot() {}
    ~Slot() {}

    template<typename... Args>
    T* init(Args&&... args) { return new(&inst) T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...); }
    void release() { inst.~T(); }
};
```

My immediate use case is for an object pool, but it would also be more generally useful.

Comment: I think what you want is called [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

Comment: @dvnrrs He's using placement new. This code looks fine to me.

Comment: @user3286380 indeed... sorry. I didn't look that closely at the code. What's the question then? There are many ways to allocate memory.

Comment: How about `char inst[sizeof(T)];`?  Or, in C++11, `alignas(T) char inst[sizeof(T)];`?

Comment: @dvnrrs I think the question was if his solution is OK.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson members in unions with constructors aren't initialized anyway so no need for a `char` buf I believe.

Comment: The obvious problems with the solution the OP gives are that it requires `T` to be default-constructable, actually creates an instance of `T` on constructed, and then ends the lifetime of that `T` without calling its destructor by constructing a new `T` over top of it.  It also has exception safety problems if the construction of the new `T` fails, since the old `T` will be destroyed by `Slot<T>`'s own destructor after having been clobbered.

Comment: you cannot use non-POD types in `union`.

Comment: @qehgt in C++11 you can.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson I don't think members of unions are constructed when the union is constructed. If they are, how would it pick which one? The exception safety is a valid point though.

Comment: @user3286380, good catch.  Didn't notice the `union` there.  But as @qehgt observes, you can't use non-PODs in unions, so the only constructors it can have are trivial compiler-generated constructors (nothing/zero-initialize for default construct, and bitwise copy for copy-construct).  That limits the utility of this solution significantly.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson see my response to qehgt.

Comment: If that's the context, this question should probably be tagged with `c++11`.

Comment: And what about using an `allocator` object where Memory allocation and object construction are seperated.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson his union has a constructor and destructor, so it must be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can use `std::aligned_storage` ([see also](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) ):

```
template<typename T> 
struct Slot {
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>::type _storage;

    Slot() {}
    ~Slot() { 
       // check if destroyed!
       ...
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    T* init(Args&&... args) { 
        return new(address()) T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...); 
    }

    void release() { (*address()).~T(); }

    T* address()  {
        return static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&_storage));
    }
};
```

Comment: @Max Notice that this class as it stands can be dangerous to use! You should make it more safe and more convenient to use ;)

Comment: It's a private inner-type, at least, so in principle the danger only lurks behind the interface.