# Aligned member variables and dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, sse

So basically, this is what I've got so far.  I have a `mat4` class, which is made up of `__m128`'s and need to be aligned on a 16-byte boundry:

```
_MM_ALIGN16
class mat4
{
   ...
};
```

I have another class which itself is not aligned, but contains a `mat4`.

```
class OtherClass
{
private:
   mat4 matrix;
   // Other data whose alignment doesn't really matter
   ...
};
```

I need to dynamically allocate instances of `OtherClass`, ala:

```
OtherClass* stuff = new OtherClass[n];
```

How can I guarantee that the `mat4` inside the instance(s) will be properly aligned, while still calling `mat4`'s constructor?

I can (and generally prefer to) use C++11's features, perhaps `aligned_storage` is what I'm looking for?  How would I use it in this case?

Comment: I've never done this, but it might be worth overloading `operator new` for your class and using an aligned memory allocator (such as `_aligned_malloc` on Visual C++, or a generic version based on regular `operator new`) underneath.

Comment: `_aligned_malloc` wont call the constructor.  I would really rather not have to overload `operator new` on every class that happens to contain a `mat4`....

Comment: `operator new` (which is different from the `new` operator) doesn't call the constructor either, and in fact it shouldn't. But your second sentence is a legitimate concern...

Comment: One way is to replace the default new operator with the largest alignment you need for all your C++ objects...

Answer (score 2):

You may use *placement new* to decouple memory allocation from object creation:

```
/* Memory allocation */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
     void *buffer = _aligned_malloc(n * sizeof(OtherClass), 16);
#else
     void *buffer = memalign(16, n * sizeof(OtherClass));
#endif
/* Object construction */
OtherClass *array = new (buffer) OtherClass[n];

/* Use your objects */
...

/* Object destruction */
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i].~OtherClass();
}
/* Memory deallocation */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
     _aligned_free(buffer);
     buffer = nullptr;
#else
     free(buffer);
     buffer = nullptr;
#endif
```

A more C++ish way would be to use std::vector with an aligned allocator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::aligned_storage` in order to define an uninitialized storage with the specified alignment in conjunction with placement new operator.

For example:

```
class OtherClass
{
private:
    using storage_t = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(mat4), 16>::type;

    storage_t _storage;

    mat4* address()  {
        return static_cast<mat4*>(static_cast<void*>(&_storage));
    }

    mat4 const* address() const {
        return static_cast<mat4 const*>(static_cast<void const*>(&_storage));
    }

public:

    OtherClass() { 
        new(address()) mat4();
    }
    OtherClass(OtherClass const& rhs) {
        new(address()) mat4(*rhs.address());
    }
    OtherClass& operator=(OtherClass const& rhs) {
        *address() = *rhs.address();
    }

    ~OtherClass() { 
       address()->~mat4(); 
    }  

    // setter
    template<typename... Args,
        class Enable = typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_constructible<mat4, Args...>::value
        >::type
    >
    void setMat(Args&&... args) {
        new(address()) mat4(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    }

    // getter
    mat4 const& getMat() const {
        return *address();
    }

    mat4& getMat() {
        return *address();
    }
    ...
};
```

**see also:**
 [std::aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)

Similar question on SO: [C++ Allocate Storage for Object without Initializing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789349/c-allocate-storage-for-object-without-initializing-it)

Comment: Would it be best to do this to allocate/deallocate `__m128`'s in the constructor/destructor of the `mat4` class?

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, if __m128 should be aligned, and mat4 is basically and array of N __m128, we certainly can implement "mat4" similar as shown above. We just need storage for N `__mat128`s, e.g. `typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(__m128), 16>::type  _storage[N];`  where each element is 16 byte aligned.

Comment: @HaydnV.Harach Note that `_storage` is _uninitialized_ storage. That is, you need "placement new operator" to construct (either copy or move) one `__m128` element. And likewise, you need to call the destructor explicitly for each element in order to destroy a `__m128`. IMO, it would be best to _initialize_ the storage in the Constructor and _destroy_ it in the Destructor.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: My bad, I thought the OP's class was called `__m128` instead of `mat4`.  I'd meant that this logic should be in the `mat4` class

Comment: @MooingDuck Of course, wherever it is more suitable :)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: I added the missing copy constructor and copy assignment, since those were obvious errors.  I think `getMat` should return by `mat4 const&`, but that's subjective so did not make that change.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, copy-ctor, and assignment operator is required. For the "get" accessor, we could also return a reference _and_ a const_reference.

Answer (score 0):

`union alignas (16) { __m128 _v; float _s[4]; };` - as an example, with the usual caveats about strict aliasing - doesn't provide a guarantee for heap storage alignment.

You may be able to avoid a new / delete implementation by querying the [std::max_align_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t) type, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973995/dynamic-aligned-memory-allocation-in-c11) answer.

Otherwise, you may need to re-implement the **global** operator new / delete functions. I don't think per-class methods are sufficient. e.g., consider a class `Camera` that has `mat4` member; If a `Camera` is instanced on the stack, then the `mat4` member alignment should be preserved. If a `Camera` object is created on the heap, I don't see how this can be otherwise enforced.

Comment: Because __m128 isn't a class, it's a special built-in data type for SSE registers.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the OP's class was `__m128` instead of `mat4`.  Why do you have a union here?  I don't understand how you intend the OP to apply this answer to his code.